# Why are Python logic operators not working with this if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I'm a newbie here and currently trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game, and in this particular if statement my 'or' somehow messes up the loop and it keeps going on forever, no matter the input. As soon as I remove it and pass the required parameter, everything falls back into place. Here's the snippet:

```
def player_input():
    '''Takes in an "X" or "O" as player's input'''
    while True:
        player1 = str(input("Player 1: please choose 'X' or 'O': "))
        if player1.lower() != 'o' or player1.lower() != 'x':
            continue
        return player1
```

Thanks in advance for all the answers!

Comment: what is the intention of this code? why do you have `return` there?

Comment: You want `and`; no matter what `player1` is, it can't be both `x` and `o` simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry, it was part of a function, I added the whole sequence to the OP

Comment: Think it should be and not or in the logic.  For instance if a person enters 'o' then it will continue since the value != 'x'.

Comment: Oh damn, and here I thought nothing could be easier than plain ol' logic... Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, this line is *always* true, hence the infinite loop:

```
if player1.lower() != 'o' or player1.lower() != 'x':
```

Think of it: if the player enters `'o'`, then it's true because `player1.lower() != 'x'` is true. If the player enters `'x'`, then it's true because `player1.lower() != 'o'` is true. If the player enters anything else, then `player1.lower() != 'o'` is true. You see the problem? it's always true, no matter what you type!

You had to use `and`, not `or`. And anyway the loop can be simplified, this is what you intended to do:

```
player1 = input("Player 1: please choose 'X' or 'O': ")
while player1.lower() != 'o' and player1.lower() != 'x':
    player1 = input("Player 1: please choose 'X' or 'O': ")
return player1
```

Comment: Yeah, see it now. Thanks for the neat explanation, kind stranger!

Answer (score 0):

You have "always True" condition. Your condition is two-part. If you put any letter except "x" or "o", you will get `True or True`. If you input "x", you will have `True or False`. If you input "o" you will get `False or True`. Anyway, finally you get "if True:", so you will continue forever.

If you want to continue until you receive `x` or `o`, you need condition:
`if player1 not in ("x", "o"):`

Comment: Thank you! I never thought I'd trip on something which seemed as simple as plain Boolean logic, but here I am (: